# Why nodejs is not allowing me to access other route when I access the root route?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the HTTP module of nodejs to create three routes('/','/about' and the last one treats any other route that is not defined as error route). When I access the root route first and try to access other route nodejs throw an error but when I access the error route or the about the route and try accessing another route it works fine.

**Below are the code I wrote and the error nodejs throw**

**Error**

```
PS C:\Users\Maxwell\Desktop\node> node app.js
node:events:368
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:846:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maxwell\Desktop\node\app.js:10:9)
    at Server.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:951:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at emitErrorNt (node:_http_outgoing:726:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
PS C:\Users\Maxwell\Desktop\node> node app.js
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:846:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maxwell\Desktop\node\app.js:10:9)
    at Server.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:951:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at emitErrorNt (node:_http_outgoing:726:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

**Code**

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    if(req.url==='/'){
    res.end('Welcome Home Dev, You are loved');
    }
    if(req.url==='/about'){
        res.end('This is the about page')
    }
    res.end(
`<h1>OOOp</h1>
<p>It seen like this page does not exit</p>

<a href='/'>back to homepage</a>

`
    );
});

server.listen(5000);
```

Comment: either use if-else or `return res.end(...`

Comment: @skara9   thanks it works fine now. I use return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to an `if/else` so you're only processing one branch of the `if` per request:

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    if(req.url === '/'){
        res.end('Welcome Home Dev, You are loved');
    } else if (req.url === '/about') {
        res.end('This is the about page')
    } else {
        res.end(
`<h1>OOOp</h1>
<p>It seen like this page does not exit</p>

<a href='/'>back to homepage</a>`);
    }
});
```

Or, alternately, you could add a `return` after each `res.send()` to stop further execution in your request handler after you send a response.  Remember, that just because you call `res.send()` your function still continues to execute so you need to manage control flow so the other code that sends a response doesn't execute once you've already sent a response.